# Ler linha específica de um arquivo txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho um arquivo de 1000 linhas e quero ler a linha 952.

Não quero ter que usar um laço para percorrer todas essas linhas, tem alguma forma mais otimizada de fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, arquivos texto são arquivos de bytes sequenciais, e como cada linha pode ter um número de bytes diferente, não há uma forma direta de ir até uma certa linha sem saber a sua posição primeiro. Para saber onde está a próxima linha é necessário ler os bytes do arquivo até encontrar o byte que indica o fim da linha. É isso que o método `readline()` e seus equivalentes fazem.

Existem exceções:

- Se **todas** as linhas do arquivo **tem o mesmo tamanho** em bytes, você pode multiplicar pelo número da linha e ir direto pra posição:

  ```
  tamanho_da_linha = 60 # todas as linhas do arquivo tem 60 bytes
  with open(nome_arq) as f:
      f.seek(tamanho_da_linha * 952) 
      # vai direto para a posicão da linha 952
      linha = f.readline()
  ```
- Se você já sabe que o arquivo tem 1000 linhas, é possível percorrer de trás pra frente e percorrer um caminho menor, apesar que isto também percorreria o arquivo, porém em sentido inverso.
- O módulo `linecache` apontado na outra resposta percorre o arquivo uma única vez e cria um índice remissivo, armazenando a posição em bytes dentro do arquivo onde se encontra cada linha. Isso permite depois que se posicione o arquivo em uma linha específica sem passar pelas demais linhas, mas é necessário percorrer o arquivo pelo menos uma vez para criar esse índice antes de usar.

Comment: Nosklo, muito obrigado pela sua resposta, ela meu deu ideias boas pra solucionar o problema.